# Why won't my function stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a return statement, and my condition is definitely being met. Yet the function still runs, not sure why.

```
<script>                                                                   
var loop = true;                                                           
fade();                                                                    
// rotate navigation banners                                               
    function fade(){                                                   
        var divs = jQuery('.site-wide-notification');                  
        var current = jQuery('.first-notification');                   
        var currentIndex = divs.index(current),                        
            nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;                              

        if (nextIndex >= divs.length){                                 
            nextIndex = 0;                                             
        }                                                              
        var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);                                 
        next.stop().fadeIn(2000, function(){                           
            jQuery(this).addClass('first-notification');               
            setTimeout(fade, 3000);                                    
        });                                                            
        current.stop().fadeOut(2000, function(){                       
            jQuery(this).removeClass('first-notification');            
        });                                                            

        jQuery('.site-wide-notification').click(function(){            
            console.log('Closed');                                     
            jQuery('.site-wide-notification').css('display', 'none');  
            loop = false;                                              
        });                                                            
        if (!loop){                                                    
            console.log('stop da loop');                               
            return false;                                              
        }                                                              
    }
```

This code is meant to rotate some banners at the top, fading them in and out, and when the user clicks on any of them it will set them all to `display: none`. When the user clicks on any of them the `console.log('Closed')` appears and loop is set to `false`, then the `if !loop` statement is entered and the console prints stop da loop, but the fade function continues running despite its return.

Comment: I don't see any loop

Comment: A function that is repeatedly called again and again setting up event handlers is almost always a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether your function returns `false` (in the `!loop` case) or `undefined` (otherwise). When you call `fade()`, it sets up a timer to call `fade()` again. Unconditionally.

Move your `if (!loop) return;` test to the top of the function. That way, if the loop isn't supposed to continue, the function bails out before setting up the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks, what would be a good solution? To call fade() in an if statement? 

    if(loop){fade()} doesnt seem to work either

Comment: Edited answer to include, you know, an answer.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm, I will give you answer when it allows me. Thanks so much :)